# Twitter integration in android without adding twitter4j.jar in lib folder

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I want to use twitter in my application. My task is to upload the twitter status from my application. I have added the twitter4j jar file in my libs folder but the issue is; API is updated now and I need to recompile the code to use twitter functionality.

Isn't there a way to use twitter API without this `twitter4j.jar` file. Because each time when an update come, we are supposed to recompile our code with this updated jar file. Isn't there a way out?

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't there a way out?

Simple answer will be "no".  When you are developing your application with any kind of third party library then you bound with that library. In future whenever that library gets update or stops its services your application also gets stop functioning.

Sometimes library updation brings smaller steps methods and removed old method which help our code to run easier.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way around this, you can only use the new twitter API directly with twitter4j. Another option is to have a Web Service from where you make the petitions. Because twitter API only allows 300 petitions every 15 minutes or so, if you want to deploy a commercial app this would turn into a big problem because twitter can even get to ban your account.

IMHO I would addapt your app to the new Twitter API using a Web Service or twitter4j, depending on your app, but there is no way to automatically update a third party library so that is why I recommend using a Web Service, these don't have to depend on any third parties. Hope it helped you out.

Comment: Sir i didn't work with web services before. Please help me that how can i use this 'twitter4j.jar' file with web service and how can i implement it. Please guide me briefly.

Comment: here is a brief tutorial to using twitter 4j and new twitter api http://hintdesk.com/how-to-tweet-in-twitter-within-android-client/ here are code examples http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html and here is another oauth connection tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/ hope it helps you out

Comment: I have gone through these links already. I am not understanding that how can i implement twitter with a web service, by placing jar file on a third place and calling its methods dynamically in my project. Please guide me.

Comment: Using a web service is not part of using twitter4j, it's another way of using twitter for android, but you have to set up a server, pay for it, etc. So in the end you would have to use twitter4j unless it is a commercial app, then use a web service.

Comment: Yes my app is a commercial app that's why i am thinking use a web service. But how can i use a twitter web service? What are the URL and the NAMESPACE which i should mention in a web service. Please guide me.

Comment: Set up a web service, here is a tutorial http://www.techrepublic.com/article/setting-up-a-simple-web-service-using-java/#. then you create a new app from the twitter api developer console as a web app and make the petitions from the web service to twitter. Then use getHttp from android to retrieve the resulting data (JSON is the most used one). I don't know how to create/manage web services so I can't be of any more help, sorry